# How to turn a 3D image into a 2D map?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, slam

As the title state's I'm trying to turn an image like this: [image]

Into a 2d map. More specifically I want to map the red lines I was able to add on top of the image. I've tried some stuff and all I was able to get was this:
[image]

Any help or tips? (I'm using mostly opencv on python for this work)

Comment: Please explain in detail what the axes of the 2D graph represent.

Comment: relative x and y positions in respect to the camera that took the picture (hope that makes sense)

Comment: Still does not make sense to me! x and y of what -- the camera location or the x,y of points along the the lines, ignoring z (in world coordinates)? If the latter, how is your world coordinate system define? Can you explain better or show a diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to transform your camera image into a bird's eye view perspective, eliminating the perspective warp of the lane markings and creating a flat 2D top-down view of the road plane.

If this is indeed what you want to achieve you can consult this tutorial for OpenCV tutorial which is doing exactly this:
[Bird's Eye View Transformation tutorial](https://nikolasent.github.io/opencv/2017/05/07/Bird's-Eye-View-Transformation.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Tried it out and worked pretty well. Than you!